# Bicep EventGrid event subscription with azure function destination with IAsyncCollector<CloudEvent> parameter

Tags: azure-bicep

I have the following bicep event subscription which results in error "Resource should pre-exist before attempting this operation." even though the function is there.

```
resource evgsProcessNewFileOnFilescom 'Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/eventSubscriptions@2023-12-15-preview' = {
  parent: customTopic
  name: 'ProcessNewFileOn'
  dependsOn: [funcFilesManagement]
  properties: {
    destination: {
      properties: {
        resourceId: '${funcFilesManagement.id}/functions/ProcessNewFile'
        maxEventsPerBatch: 1
        preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes: 64
      }
      endpointType: 'AzureFunction'
    }
    filter: {
      includedEventTypes: [
        'new-file'
      ]
      enableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays: true
    }
    labels: []
    eventDeliverySchema: 'CloudEventSchemaV1_0'
    retryPolicy: {
      maxDeliveryAttempts: 30
      eventTimeToLiveInMinutes: 1440
    }
  }
}
```

The function is defined as,

```
[FunctionName("ProcessNewFile")]
public async Task ProcessNewFile(
    [EventGridTrigger] CloudEvent @event,
    [EventGrid(TopicEndpointUri = "ImporterTopicEndpoint", TopicKeySetting = "ImporterTopicKey")] IAsyncCollector<CloudEvent> eventCollector,
    ILogger log)
```

When I use a function without the EventGrid output binding,

```
[EventGrid(TopicEndpointUri = "ImporterTopicEndpoint", TopicKeySetting = "ImporterTopicKey")] IAsyncCollector<CloudEvent> eventCollector
```

there is no error and the event subscription is created successfully.

I am stuck and would be grateful for help and pointers.